# Term for infinite rectangular prism

Tags: infinity, rectangles

Is there a mathematical name for the shape in three dimensions that is only bounded by $0<z<6$? Or is infinite rectangular prism the best way to describe this?

Comment: I'd call it a _slab_, but would explain the term at its first usage.

Comment: "Infinite rectangular prism" is probably not a good term - if I saw the term and had to guess its meaning, I would think it implied a rectangular prism of infinite height - so a region defined by both $0<x<1$ and $0<y<2$, for instance (but I wouldn't be very certain of this guess, unless the term was explicitly defined in the text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided bounds on x and y, it can be thought of as a cylinder or cuboid depending on what measure of distance you apply.

Comment: Doesn't a cuboid have to be bounded by six sides? Would it just be a cylinder with infinite radius?

Comment: You've defined the "top" and "bottom sides" by the planes z = 0 and z = 6. Because x and y are unbounded, how you imagine the set growing to infinity is how you define the shape of the set (which again has little meaning here because the set is not bounded). You could envision the euclidean distance to the origin (whose equidistant sets form a circle) or it could be that you envision the sum of the absolute values of x and y which defines a rectangle if I recall correctly